# JQuery add button to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a grid inside a `div` that is dynamically added, where when you select a `tr` in the `grid` it adds a class, `grid-row-selected`, that highlights the `tr`. So what I'm trying to do is create a jquery or javascript `function` that when the `tr` is highlighted and adds the class, a button will be created in the `ibox-tools`. Also if the `grid-row-selected` is removed so is the button. This is what i have right now that doesn't work (wont add a button).

**JQUERY**

```
/* Function is called when a tr is selected with the grid-row class */
$("tr.grid-row").click(function() {
    /* Checks if this class is selected and has grid-row-selected class */
    if ($(this).hasClass(".grid-row-selected") ) {
        /* Adds button to ibox-tools in div */
        $(".ibox-tools").add($('<input type="button" value="new button"/>'));
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ibox-title">
    // Where the button should be populated into
    <div class="ibox-tools">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enlargeGraphOneModal" data-content="#ibox-2"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ibox-content" id="ibox-2">
    <div class="content active row" id="graphOneData" style="overflow:auto">
        <!--GRID DYNAMICALLY ADDED-->
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
            {
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.DisplayName).Titled("Display Name").Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.Description).Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.ModifiedBy).Titled("Modified By").Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.ModifiedOn).Titled("Modified On").Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.StartYear).Titled("Start Year").Sortable(true);
            columns.Add(scenario => scenario.EndYear).Titled("End Year").Sortable(true);
            }).WithPaging(20).Sortable()
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is "ibox-tools" css class in your HTML?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Do you mean where do i call the link to my css page in my html or what is the css for ibox exactly?

Comment: you are trying to add a button to a control with class ".ibox-tools". I am not able to see the ".ibox-tools" class in html, at first place. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/141/ (you must have a control with class "ibox-tools" inorder to append another control in it.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh ah i see what youre asking, i was missing some HTML on the ibox-tools. I added it now to clarify it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid is added dynamically. So the 'tr.grid-row' doesn't exist when your code adds the event listener. Using the '.on' method creates a delegated function that gets added to elements dynamically added to the DOM. You also have to make sure this code runs after the code that adds the 'grid-row-selected' class to the row on click otherwise the row won't have the class. It would be better if you could add this code to that function.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', 'tr.grid-row', function() {
        /* Checks if this class is selected and has grid-row-selected class */
        if ($(this).hasClass(".grid-row-selected") ) {
            /* Adds button to ibox-tools in div */
            $('#gridEdit').remove();
            $(".ibox-tools").append($('<input id="gridEdit" type="button" value="new button"/>'));
        }
    });
});
```

this also depends on the version of jQuery you are using. for older versions it's '.live()'. I'm not sure in what version it changed.

EDIT: There was a typo in my code. I had an extra '(' in front of 'function'. A copy/paste error. if you try it now it should work as long as this code is run AFTER the code that adds the 'grid-row-selected' class to the tr. http://jsfiddle.net/rgkw9pLs/

Comment: This definitely seems like its on the right track but it didn't end up adding a button unfortunately.

Comment: @Markus see my edit above. There was a typo in the code.

Comment: Awesome i got it working, the only thing that was messing with it was the "." in front of "grid-row-selected", once i removed that it worked. Quick question, do you know how to make it so when i click a different "tr" in the grid the button that was added will be removed and a new button is added. I only want one edit button in the ibox-tools at a time.

Comment: The easy way would be $('.ibox-tools').clear().append('<input type="button" value="new button" />');. The '.clear()' will remove all html from inside the ibox-tools div.

Comment: oh i dont ant to remove all html, just the buttons that i added with the jquery

Comment: then i would add a specific class to the buttons you add like $('.ibox-tools').append('<input type="button" class="added-btn" value="new button" />');. Then you can remove them with $('.added-btn').remove() before you add the new one.

Comment: Awesome ! It works. Do you mind just editing your answer to include that so i can mark your answer as correct ? What i put that worked was `$(function () {
    $("body").one('click', 'tr.grid-row', function () {
        /* Checks if this class is selected and has grid-row-selected class */
        if ($(this).hasClass("grid-row-selected")) {
            /* Remove buttons from ibox-tools */
            $('#gridEdit').remove()
            /* Adds buttons to ibox-tools in div */
            $(".ibox-tools").prepend($('<input type="button" id="gridEdit" value="Edit"/>'));
        }
    });
});`

Answer (score 2):

the problem is your hasclass validation and method
It should be:

```
$("tr.grid-row").click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass("grid-row-selected") ) {
    alert("test")
    $(".ibox-tools").append($('<input type="button" value="new button"/>'));
} });
```

[Example fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf2vjfcz/)

Comment: Awesome that worked! But how do i have it that it only adds one button? Im trying to have it so when a user clicks the "tr" an edit button will pop up, so they wont need more than one. Also do you know how to get it to spawn on the left side of the buttons i already have in the ibox-tools?

Answer (score 0):

try to use "append" instead of "add"

```
$(".ibox-tools").append('<input type="button" value="new button"/>');
```